# How can I update fetch request in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am fetching a quotes API. Here I want to update the quotes randomly but I want to update the quotes on button click. I have no idea how to do that. Can anyone help me to do so?

I have fetched data using fetch request then add data to state.

> This is my code

```
import React from "react";    
import "./styles.css";    
class Box extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      quote: "",
      author: ""
    };
  }    
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }
  fetchData = () => {
    fetch(
      "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json"
    )
      .then(result => {
        return result.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        const ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.quotes.length);       
        console.log(data.quotes[ran].quote);
        console.log(data.quotes[ran].author);
        this.setState({
          quote: data.quotes[ran].quote,
          author: data.quotes[ran].author
        });
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="quote-box" className="container">
        <div className="box-container">
          <div className="text-center">
            <h1 id="text">{this.state.quote}</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="float-right">
            <p id="author">
              <span>- </span>
              {this.state.author}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="box-item">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-6">Twitter</div>
            <div className="col-sm-6">
              <button>next quote</button>  <--- Here i want this button to update quotes on screen.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Box;
```

Comment: Why not just call this.fetchData again? Or store all the quotes the first time you call it, so you can generate a new random index without another network call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is, store the quote array that you've fetched to a state so you wont need to fetch it again when you want to display another quote.

```
this.state = {
  quoteArray: [],  <----- This one
  quote: "",
  author: ""
};
```

Then create a separate function that will get random quote from that quoteArray

```
pickRandomQuote = () => {
   const ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.quotes.length);      
   this.setState({
     quote: this.state.quoteArray[ran].quote,
     author: this.state.quoteArray[ran].author
   });
}
```

In your fetch function, store the array you fetched to the state and then call the `pickRandomQuote` after

```
fetchData = () => {
    fetch(
"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json"
    )
      .then(result => {
        return result.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          quoteArray: data
        });
        this.pickRandomQuote();
      });
  };
```

Then to generate new random quote, just put this to your button

```
<button onClick={() => this.pickRandomQuote()}>next quote</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

render: `<button onClick={this.fetchData}>next quote</button>`

constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    quote: "",
    author: ""
  };
  this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Thank you actually I forgot to bind the function that's why I was getting infinite loop may be.

Comment: This is not a good idea because it will unnecessarily fetch new data every button click. Check my answer on how to properly do it